# How to fix a UnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: python, utf-8, byte, spyder

So I'm trying to combine several files from a folder on my desktop. Additionally I am trying to remove several row above my actual data. This ran perfectly when I tested it out on some tester files but now I keep getting the following error. I've looked up similar issues through stack overflow I just can't figure out how to make this work.

**Error Code**

```
runcell(0, '/Users/laurendonati/Desktop/Tester/Combine_?')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/laurendonati/Desktop/Tester/Combine_?", line 27, in <module>
    for i, row in enumerate(f):

  File "/Users/laurendonati/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1055: invalid start byte
```

#Working Code

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from itertools import islice
import io
#%matplotlib inline
#%pylab inline

path = '/Users/laurendonati/Desktop/AssateagueIsland_Data/CTD Pond Drivers /17B/17B_CSV'
df=pd.DataFrame()
for each in os.scandir(path):
    with io.open(each,'r') as f:
        meta= csv.reader(f)
        substring="Date/time"
        for i, row in enumerate(f):
            if substring in row:
                st=i
        with open(each,'r') as f:
            meta=csv.reader(f)
            top=list(islice(meta,st+53))
        df_app=pd.read_csv(each,skiprows=st)
        df=df.append(df_app)
           
             
temp= df["Temperature[°C]"]
Conductivity= df["2:Spec.cond.[mS/cm]"]
SpecificConductance= (Conductivity)/ (1 + 0.02 * (temp - 25))
##df["Specific Conductivity"]= SpecificConductance
##df_new= pd.DataFrame({"Specific Conductvity":[SpecificConductance]})
##df=df.append(df_new,"\n")
df['Specific Conductivity']= SpecificConductance

df.to_csv('/Users/laurendonati/Desktop/Tester/Round_T_wo.csv')
```

Comment: When you open a file, you should declare the encoding of such file. In this case: your file is not UTF-8 (and Python assume UTF-8 in most (but not all) modern operating systems. Your file may be just Latin1 or some windows encoding, so just put it into open (for this reason one should always be explicit on encoding, else you get surprises).

Comment: I'm just not sure how to do this for the entire directory. Could you give me an example?